# json to instance using TypeName

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to find a way to create an instance of a class from the full type name of the class and the json representation of the instance.

```
var classTypeFullName = "something.type";
var classType = Type.GetType(classTypeFullName);
var instanceJson = "{....}";
var classInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(instanceJson, classType);
```

My problem is it is always returning a JObject, i need it to return the instance type. If i knew the type before the code ran I would normal just do the following:

```
var classInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(instanceJson);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for an answer to something like this.

The C# Core2.2 application was not loading the assembly as it was a dependency of a referenced dll. As such the classType was null  and therefore the Deserialization was always coming back as a JObject not the expect type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, i did it some time ago.

```
convert yr Json to dynamic dynamicObj, and have the full assembly name

var type = Type.GetType("something.type");
var obj = Convert.ChangeType(dynamicObj.Result, type);
```

Comment: in a way you are going to need an stateobject inc the TypeOff that you are expecting back, to help out in multiThreading